# Google App Engine and PHP Blank Page after deploying to the cloud. (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS)

Tags: php, html, google-app-engine, yaml

I'm trying to make an app that lets users authenticate before login into a service. I'm using Google App Engine and PHP; The application works fine in my computer but after I deploy to the Google Cloud, the PHP files doesn't work.  I have all the files in the root directory.

This is my app.yaml

```
application: civil-topic-94103
version: 1
runtime: php55
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /registration.php*
  script: registration.php

- url: /login.php*
  script: login.php

- url: /
  static_files: homepage.html
  upload: homepage.html

# access the static resources in the root directory

- url: /(.*)
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*)
```

This is my login.html file:

```
<html>
<head>
 <title>login</title>
 </head>
 <body>
    <p><b>Please Login</b></p>   <br>
    <form action="login.php" method="post">
    User: <input type="text" name="username"><br>
    Pass: <input type="text" name="password"><br>
    <input type="submit">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my login.php testing file:

```
<?php
echo "message";
?>
INCORRECT USERNAME and/or Password
```

This is my log:
[image]

After clicking the submit button in login.html, I get a blank page.

Does someone know what is going on??

Comment: If you change `- url: /login.php*` to `- url: /login.html` does it any change?

Comment: The last handler in your app.yaml looks like the culprit here. Try remove it or put your static assets in a folder rather than under the root.

Comment: doru:                                                                                                             If I substitude " - url: /login.php* " to " - url: /login.html" , I get a blank page instead of getting the login.html output.

Comment: You are correct Mars!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is how I solved the problem:
 I took some code from this website https://gist.github.com/darktable/873098

I created a directory named "staticfiles" and moved all html files to it(exept the homepage.html).

I changed:

```
- url: /(.*)
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*)
```

with

```
- url: /(.*\.html)
  mime_type: text/html
  static_files: staticfiles/\1
  upload: staticfiles/(.*\.html)
```